# Influx - just starting to get "authorization not found" error after having connected before

Tags: authorization, influxdb, bucket, influxdb-2

Using Windows downloadable EXEs for Influx.   Was connecting and working great until this morning.

I started `influxd` today, and I see in the console:

```
c:\Influx>influxd
2021-06-10T06:21:49.336269Z     info    Welcome to InfluxDB     {"log_id": "0Ue9Baal000", "version": "2.0.7", "commit": "2a45f0c037", "build_date": "2021-06-04T19:17:40Z"}
2021-06-10T06:21:49.341178Z     info    Resources opened        {"log_id": "0Ue9Baal000", "service": "bolt", "path": "C:\\Users\\guyl\\.influxdbv2\\influxd.bolt"}
2021-06-10T06:21:49.355301Z     info    Checking InfluxDB metadata for prior version.   {"log_id": "0Ue9Baal000", "bolt_path": "C:\\Users\\guyl\\.influxdbv2\\influxd.bolt"}
2021-06-10T06:21:49.356219Z     info    Using data dir  {"log_id": "0Ue9Baal000", "service": "storage-engine", "service": "store", "path": "C:\\Users\\guyl\\.influxdbv2\\engine\\data"}
2021-06-10T06:21:49.356219Z     info    Compaction settings     {"log_id": "0Ue9Baal000", "service": "storage-engine", "service": "store", "max_concurrent_compactions": 4, "throughput_bytes_per_second": 50331648, "throughput_bytes_per_second_burst": 50331648}
2021-06-10T06:21:49.356219Z     info    Open store (start)      {"log_id": "0Ue9Baal000", "service": "storage-engine", "service": "store", "op_name": "tsdb_open", "op_event": "start"}
2021-06-10T06:21:49.391834Z     info    index opened with 8 partitions  {"log_id": "0Ue9Baal000", "service": "storage-engine", "index": "tsi"}
2021-06-10T06:21:49.392819Z     info    index opened with 8 partitions  {"log_id": "0Ue9Baal000", "service": "storage-engine", "index": "tsi"}
2021-06-10T06:21:49.397817Z     info    Reading file    {"log_id": "0Ue9Baal000", "service": "storage-engine", "engine": "tsm1", "service": "cacheloader", "path": "C:\\Users\\guyl\\.influxdbv2\\engine\\wal\\3198a3a2f58ea23a\\autogen\\2\\_00001.wal", "size": 1401771}
2021-06-10T06:21:49.397817Z     info    Reading file    {"log_id": "0Ue9Baal000", "service": "storage-engine", "engine": "tsm1", "service": "cacheloader", "path": "C:\\Users\\guyl\\.influxdbv2\\engine\\wal\\3198a3a2f58ea23a\\autogen\\1\\_00001.wal", "size": 10498778}
2021-06-10T06:21:49.516021Z     info    Opened shard    {"log_id": "0Ue9Baal000", "service": "storage-engine", "service": "store", "op_name": "tsdb_open", "index_version": "tsi1", "path": "C:\\Users\\guyl\\.influxdbv2\\engine\\data\\3198a3a2f58ea23a\\autogen\\2", "duration": "140.184ms"}
2021-06-10T06:21:50.165166Z     info    Reading file    {"log_id": "0Ue9Baal000", "service": "storage-engine", "engine": "tsm1", "service": "cacheloader", "path": "C:\\Users\\guyl\\.influxdbv2\\engine\\wal\\3198a3a2f58ea23a\\autogen\\1\\_00002.wal", "size": 2714197}
2021-06-10T06:21:50.356368Z     info    Opened shard    {"log_id": "0Ue9Baal000", "service": "storage-engine", "service": "store", "op_name": "tsdb_open", "index_version": "tsi1", "path": "C:\\Users\\guyl\\.influxdbv2\\engine\\data\\3198a3a2f58ea23a\\autogen\\1", "duration": "980.511ms"}
2021-06-10T06:21:50.357325Z     info    Open store (end)        {"log_id": "0Ue9Baal000", "service": "storage-engine", "service": "store", "op_name": "tsdb_open", "op_event": "end", "op_elapsed": "1001.082ms"}
2021-06-10T06:21:50.359335Z     info    Starting retention policy enforcement service   {"log_id": "0Ue9Baal000", "service": "retention", "check_interval": "30m"}
2021-06-10T06:21:50.359335Z     info    Starting precreation service    {"log_id": "0Ue9Baal000", "service": "shard-precreation", "check_interval": "10m", "advance_period": "30m"}
2021-06-10T06:21:50.360336Z     info    Starting query controller       {"log_id": "0Ue9Baal000", "service": "storage-reads", "concurrency_quota": 1024, "initial_memory_bytes_quota_per_query": 9223372036854775807, "memory_bytes_quota_per_query": 9223372036854775807, "max_memory_bytes": 0, "queue_size": 1024}
2021-06-10T06:21:50.362322Z     info    Configuring InfluxQL statement executor (zeros indicate unlimited).     {"log_id": "0Ue9Baal000", "max_select_point": 0, "max_select_series": 0, "max_select_buckets": 0}
2021-06-10T06:21:50.684777Z     info    Starting        {"log_id": "0Ue9Baal000", "service": "telemetry", "interval": "8h"}
2021-06-10T06:21:50.684777Z     info    Listening       {"log_id": "0Ue9Baal000", "service": "tcp-listener", "transport": "http", "addr": ":8086", "port": 8086}
2021-06-10T06:21:57.610274Z     info    Unauthorized    {"log_id": "0Ue9Baal000", "error": "authorization not found"}
2021-06-10T06:22:07.611932Z     info    Unauthorized    {"log_id": "0Ue9Baal000", "error": "authorization not found"}
2021-06-10T06:22:17.616794Z     info    Unauthorized    {"log_id": "0Ue9Baal000", "error": "authorization not found"}
2021-06-10T06:22:27.630195Z     info    Unauthorized    {"log_id": "0Ue9Baal000", "error": "authorization not found"}
2021-06-10T06:22:37.643137Z     info    Unauthorized    {"log_id": "0Ue9Baal000", "error": "authorization not found"}
```

First I thought maybe it was because my influx.conf file had an outdated token, so I updated it:

```
[default]
  url = "http://localhost:8086"
  token = "my updated token=="
  org = "My company name"
  active = true
```

I tried `influxd` again, but I got the same result.

I ran from an Admin DOS shell.

The db is running, because I can log into the website, but it seems I cannot get to my bucket:

[image]

Here are my two tokens:
[image]

"Load Tester's Token" has read/write for everything, exactly as I created it.
[image]

It was this token I put into my `influx.conf` file.  (It changed, for some reason.)

My `load_bucket` retention is now 1 year.  I tried changing it to forever, but even if I save my changes, it stays 1 year.

I also tried creating a new bucket and writing to it from a script, but the script fails to connect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow below steps:

1. Execute below command to check if you can access the `auth` list and see all tokens list and if you have read-write permissions :
   `influx.exe auth list`
   You can also view in dasboard:
   [image]
2. If you are not able to see token, then you can generate a token with read/write or all access.
   [image]

3. It might have also happened that the retention period that you choose must have been over due to which no measurement data is available.
4. You can create a new bucket and add token that you created in above step:

```
influx.exe bucket create --name <Nameofyourdb> --org <Organistaion name> --description <"Your description"> --token <token string>
```

5. Write your measurement data:

```
influx.exe write --bucket <Nameofyourdb> --host http://localhost:8086 "m,host=host1 field1=1.2"
```

Comment: @Guy does this work for you and also the tokens that you are using must have read write access as mentioned in the answer

Comment: What I wrote in my updated post was that the tokens are in fact read-write.

Comment: @Guy did you try to create a bucket with the same command that I posted?

Comment: Yes - they both worked!  Just for the heck of it, I'll do the same with the original bucket and see what happens....  And it did.  So this is really weird.  What happened to all the stuff that used to be in `load_bucket`?

Comment: I don't know the explanation, but my Python script is able to write to the original bucket now.  I still see the `authorization not found` messages, though.